# Is continuity necessary to prove that a function $f$ satisfying $\forall x \in [a,b]: \lim_{y \to x}f(x)=L_x \in \mathbb R$ is bounded on $[a,b]$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, soft-question

I was reviewing some of my book's theorems on continuity (*Chapter 7 of Spivak's Calculus*) and began to wonder if the assumptions of continuity were actually necessary for several of the proofs.

---

One such example is:

> If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is bounded above on $[a,b] \quad (\dagger_1)$.

The proof that follows for $(\dagger_1)$ depends on another theorem, which is written as:

> If $f$ is continuous at $a$, then there is a number $\delta \gt 0$ such that $f$ is bounded above on the interval $(a-\delta,a+\delta) \quad (\dagger_2)$.

After looking at $(\dagger_2)$'s proof more closely, I am not sure I  see why I need continuity to  establish that $f$ is bounded above.

**Here is the book's proof of $(\dagger_2)$**:

> Since $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a}f(x)=f(a)$, there is, for every $\varepsilon \gt 0$, a $\delta \gt 0$ such that, for all $x$, \begin{align}\text{ if } |x-a| \lt \delta\text{ , then } |f(x)-f(a)| \lt \varepsilon \end{align} It is only necessary to apply this statement to some particular $\varepsilon$ (any one will do), for example, $\varepsilon =1$. We conclude that there is a $\delta \gt 0$ such that, for all $x$, \begin{align}\text{if } |x-a| \lt \delta \text{ , then } |f(x) - f(a)| \lt 1 \end{align} It follows, in particular, that if $|x-a| \lt \delta$, then $f(x)< f(a)+1$. This completes the proof: on the interval $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$ the function $f$ is bounded above by $f(a)+1$.

It seems to me that I could switch out the continuity assumption for what I think is a weaker assumption, namely that $f(a) \in \mathbb R$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L_a \in \mathbb R$, and, with minor adjustments, conclude that on the interval $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$, the function $f$ is bounded above by $|f(a)|+1$ This would be given by the idea that, if $f$ is **not** continuous at $a$, then $f(a) \lt \displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ or $f(a) \gt \displaystyle \lim_{x \to a}f(x)$

---

With this new version of $(\dagger_2)$, I am fairly certain that removing the assumption of continuity from $(\dagger_1)$ would not preclude me from arriving at the consequent.

**Am I wrong in my thinking**? If not, why are these proofs making the continuity assumption?

Maybe this question comes down to: is $f(a) \in \mathbb R$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L_a \in \mathbb R$ a weaker assumption than $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a}f(x)=f(a)$?

Comment: If $f$ has a  finite limit at each pint $x$  of $[a,b]$ then $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$ . Continuity is not needed.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Then I am guessing that it is also the case that if $f$ has a finite limit at each point $x$ of $[a,b]$, then $f$ has a minimum/maximum on $[a,b]$? (continuity not needed)

Comment: Another way of looking at it: If $f$ has a limit at every point in a compact set, then there are a finite number of points of the set where $f$ is not continuous, and the function $L_x$ is continuous on the set. So $f$ is bounded by a combination of the bounds of $L_x$ and the finite set of values at its discontinuous points.

Comment: @aschepler The Thomae function has limit everywhere but is not discontinuous at $q$ for all  $q\in \mathbb Q$.

Comment: Check the proof for the theorem which says that functions which are continuous on a closed interval attain their minimum and maximum value. For bounded functions we get the sup and inf of its values but without continuity we can't ensure that these values are attained (so as to become max, min).

Comment: +1 for this question. This is the way one should look at given proofs by trying to figure out the key ideas and checking the necessity of assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ has a finite limit at each pint $x$ of $[a,b]$ then f is bounded on $[a,b]$. Continuity is not needed.

$f(x)=x$ for $0 <x\leq 1$, $f(0)=1$ has finite limit at each point but it does not attain its minimum.